# Android PdfRenderer not working with certain PDF files

Tags: android, pdf

I am currently trying to use the PDFRenderer class which requires a minSDK of 21. For the most part, I followed the example from [here](https://github.com/digipost/Android-Pdf). It renders fine for most PDF files but it seems like whenever I try to throw it a PDF file made by LaTeX it fails. I'm not completely sure if this is the case, but here is a link to an example of a PDF that does not work: http://www.cs.ucr.edu/~mkrtchyk/CS111_files/asymptotic_notation.pdf. I'm completely lost at the moment as I can't find a legitimate reason as to why it should not work. Below are pictures of it working fine with one PDF, while unable to correctly render the other. I know since PdfRenderer is new, there will not be many people who are familiar with this, but if you have a hint on what may be causing this issue, please let me know. Thank you[image: ![working]][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zDCsT.png)[[image: not working]][4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Crhmp.png)

Comment: I'm also seeing this with certain documents, that text isn't being rendered even when other things are. I'm not the author so I don't know how they were made. Did you ever figure out a way around this? I tried using pdftk to flatten the file but even that's not enough.

Comment: I have the same problem rendering this PDF https://db.cbg-meb.nl/Bijsluiters/h24104.pdf it does show everything except the text. I can see the short lines and header, but not the text. Any updates  on this problem?

Answer (score 0):

The file you have linked seems to be correct but there could be an issue with PDFRenderer and PDF 1.5 format. You may check the PDF file format version used by opening the PDF in Notepad and looking at the begining of the file, the version of PDF format is set like this:

```
%PDF-1.5...
```

In general, the lower format (1.4, 1.3 ) the simplier the structure of PDF file is, and vice versa. You should be aware of some other issues with PDFRenderer like [partial page rendering][1].

Comment: Thanks for this reply, but I have multiple PDFs with version 1.5, most of them are working, except this particular one. So I think it is not a specific version problem

Comment: @greet.. The issue is not with PDF version, Pdfrenderer is not supporting the custom fonts and styles.

If anyone having any luck rendering PDF with custom font & styles, please post.